# Web Application server migration

Tags: web-application

While testing web application migrations to newer servers, what kinds of gotchya's should I be looking out for.  I think that I have a pretty good handle on most of the testing, however, I have this sinking feeling that I'm missing something.  As for the technology being used, it's mostly ASP classic with a little bit of .NET, so, obviously on a windows infrastruture.

Answer (score 1):

Two things come to head about new server migration.

- New server environment (version differences can lead to incorrectly working application (deprecated methods, new environment bugs and so on));
- Incorrect new server configuration;

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider what is changing, and what is not.

- Newer hardware, but unchanged software?
- Newer software?
- Applications changes, too?
- Any configuration changes?

Comment: To expand a little on Joe's answer, consider also:
what has changed that should not?
what has not changed that should?
I don't know if looking at the setup of the new machine(s) falls within your jurisdiction, but you may also look at things like disk partitioning, how and where logs are written, required connectivity between other machines, error reporting for various modes of failure.